# MeanJS - Adding ArticleID to Comment Mongo Collection

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have 2 Collections of article and comment and i would like to add the articleID to the Comment Collection when creating a new comment. The same way in which the UserID automatically goes in.

**comment.client.controller.js**

```
// Create new Comment
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Comment object
        var comment = new Comments ({


            details: this.details,
            status: this.status,
            created: this.created,



        });

        // Redirect after save
        comment.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('comments/' + response._id);

            // Clear form fields
            $scope.status = '';
            $scope.details = '';
            $scope.created = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```

**comment.server.model.js**

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
userName: {
    type: String,
    default: 'To Do',
    required: 'Please fill Comment name',
    trim: true
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
details: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
}
,
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
article: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Article'
}
```

});

Essentially what i need to know is where does the ObJectID for the User come from without having user : this.user or similar like you need for details, status and created. How can i get the same for Article to just automatically include the Article ObjectID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id will come from the route itself or if you intentionally send it inside the POST request body.

**Example with article id in route:**
If a user posts a comment to an article (with id 123456789) it will make a POST request to `/api/articles/123456789/posts` then in the backend of the app you will have the endpoint defined as follows:

```
app.route('/api/articles/:articleId/posts').post(article.postComment);
```

Note the `:articleId` in the route, now what you can do is bind that route param to use in your server controllers like so:

```
app.param('articleId', article.articleById);
```

`articleById` is the middleware that will use mongoose to find the article. `articleById` is defined in the article server controllers file.

Then in your `postComment` controller you can access the id using `req.article`.

If you take a look at the server routes for the articles module in meanjs, you will notice that it was already done, so you can probably use the `req.article` to access the article id.